# How can I make the iPhone recording and playback audio level meter look the same?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, audio, volume

I display an audio level meter for recording and playback of that recording. The level values are from 0 - 1.0. I draw a bar representing the 0 - 1.0 value on screen. To get the audio levels for recording I use:

```
OSStatus status = AudioQueueGetProperty(aqData.mQueue, kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeter, aqLevelMeterState, &levelMeterStateDataSize);

float level = aqLevelMeterState[0].mAveragePower;
```

For playback I use:

```
// soundPlayer is an AVSoundPlayer
float level = [soundPlayer averagePowerForChannel:0];
```

I normalize level from 0 - 1.0.

Right now they look very different when showing the bar. The recording meter bar is more on the low end while the playback bar meter, when playing back that same recorded audio, stays more in the middle.

I'm trying to make the two meters look the same, but I'm fairly new to audio. I've done a bit of research and know that the recording is returning an RMS value and the playback is returning it in decibels.

Can someone knowledgeable in audio point me to links or documents, or give a little hint to make sense of these two values so that I can start making them look the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the RMS or root mean square for a given timer interval.  RMS is calculated by summing the square of each signal value for the total, divining that the number of samples to get the mean and then taking the square root of the mean.

```
     uint64 avgTotal;
    for(int i =0; i < sampleCount; i++)
       avgTotal+= (sample[i]*sample[i])/(uint64)sampleCount; //divide to help with overlfow

    float rms = sqrt(avgTotal);
```

You will have to understand enough about the data you a playing to get the signal values. The durration of time that you consider should not matter that much. 50-80ms should do it.

Comment: Hmm. Since recording is in RMS I will do this for the playback values. I guess I'll try to use the decibel value as the sample then and see how that goes. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem like it. You're right, I need to know more about the data. I guess thats what my question is mainly about. They say mAveragePower is RMS and I sort of understand what that is, but what did they use to get it? Is average power the RMS of the decibals and then normalized 0 - 1.0 etc? Maybe I'll add that to the question or post a follow up question to get details about those values.

Comment: RMS is based on the sample values. An audio signal is composed of samples at a given sample rate. It really has nothing to do with decibals. Read about PCM here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation  Might help.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. This definitely requires more study. My solution for now is have both return the decibals. I'll finagle with the data from there. =)

Answer (score 1):

Decibels are logarithmically scaled.  So you probably want some equation such as:

```
myDb = 20.0 * log (myRMS / scaleFactor);
```

somewhere, where you'd have to calibrate the scaleFactor to match up the values you want for full scale.